# C++: Confusion on converting integers to roman numerals

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm working on a program for my C++ course. The guidelines are to create a converter that turns integers to roman numerals, the specifications being that I must use at least one while statement,  do while statement, and one switch.

My code isworking for the most part, but I can't involve special cases involving 4 and 9 (such as (4, 14, 24 34, etc) 40, (140, 240, etc) 400, (1400, 2400, 3400, etc) and (9, 19, 29, 39, etc) 90, (190, 290, etc) 900, 9000)) to work for me. This is the code I have at this point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{ 
   cout << "Please enter  an interger." << endl;
   int num = 0;
   cin >> num;
   string rep = "";     


     switch(num)
   {
      case 40:                                    
      rep += "XL"; 
      num -= 40;                                   
      break;                                     
      case 90:
      rep += "XC";
      num -= 90;
      break;
   }


      if (num >= 1000){
         rep += string(num / 1000,'M');
         num %= 1000;
      }
      if (num >= 500){
          rep += string(num / 500,'D');
          num %= 500;
      }
      if (num >= 100){
          rep += string(num / 100,'C');
          num %= 100;

      }
      if (num >= 50){
          rep += string(num / 50,'L');
          num %= 50;

      }
      if (num >= 10){
          rep += string(num / 10,'X');
          num %= 10;
      }
      if (num >= 5){
          rep += string(num / 5,'V');
          num %= 5;
      }    
      if (num >= 1){
         rep += string(num,'I');
         num %= 1;
      }


      cout << num << endl;
      cout << rep << endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Those are some pretty dumb specifications.  (That your teacher specified)

Comment: @nhgrif: well, the ostensible purpose of the code is to convert an integer to Roman numerals, but that objective is completely useless even though it does something apparently constructive. The real purpose of the exercise is to learn those three control structures, which is extremely useful even though it may be irrelevant to the ostensible purpose of the code. Fundamentally, real-looking tasks are not necessarily the best way to learn syntax :-)

Comment: That's why I think the specifications are dumb.  Learning syntax should be done in class lecture, on quizzes, or as part of miniscule homework assignments: "Write a for loop." for example.  Actual projects like this shouldn't have requirements outside what the program should accomplish as a whole, and the student should be graded on his ability to implement the best control structures.

Comment: @nhgrif: unfortunately if you do that, someone complains that the minuscule assignments are boring/abstract/un-engaging etc, even more loudly than you're complaining that the Roman numerals project is dumb. Personally I like boring, abstract, un-engaging introductions to a programming language, but I'm not normal. Neither are most people who make it to reasonable programming proficiency. Introductory exercises aren't really for them.

Comment: In my programming classes, I never had miniscule projects.  We had quizzes that covered basic syntax (and took 15 minutes to do, online, in my own time), and we had projects which were open for 2-3 weeks at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(num)
{
case 40:                                    
   rep += "XL"; 
   num -= 40;                                   
   break;                                     
case 90:
   rep += "XC";
   num -= 90;
   break;
}
```

They only work when the number is exact `40` or `90`. Try to separate the number rather than comparing equality.

Comment: How would I go about doing that while maintaining the switch that's supposed to exist in my project?

Comment: @Titanguy654 Simply don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it by first finding an appropriate algorithm (Google produced useful results for me), and then, after implementing it, I'd find a way to shove in the three control structures required.

I suspect that the requirements might actually help you.  For example, let's consider a simple conversion, the number 2000.  [This should produce "MM"](http://www.onlineconversion.com/roman_numerals_advanced.htm).

So let's start with that idea.  Your algorithm needs to be something like:

```
while (the number is greater than zero) {
  Check if the number is greater than 1000.  If so, take 1000 off the number and put an "M" in the string.
}
```

This code uses a while loop (something your current code is missing).

You could then move on to a new test case, such as 100.  This should produce "C".  Then I'd work on 200, and 300, getting that same while loop from above to do the work.

I found an interesting algorithm online that checked for greater than 400 and less than 500 and replaced it with "CD".  Perhaps that will help your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

From http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Encode#C.2B.2B

```
std::string to_roman(unsigned int value)
{
    struct romandata_t { unsigned int value; char const* numeral; };
    const struct romandata_t romandata[] =
    {
        {1000, "M"}, {900, "CM"},
        {500, "D"}, {400, "CD"},
        {100, "C"}, { 90, "XC"},
        { 50, "L"}, { 40, "XL"},
        { 10, "X"}, { 9, "IX"},
        { 5, "V"}, { 4, "IV"},
        { 1, "I"},
        { 0, NULL} // end marker
    };

    std::string result;
    for (const romandata_t* current = romandata; current->value > 0; ++current)
    {
        while (value >= current->value)
        {
            result += current->numeral;
            value -= current->value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```